# How can I avoid self-managing z-index on leaflet popups

Tags: leaflet

**UPDATED INLINE**

Using Leaflet 0.7 (but I would like to move to 1.0 Beta 2) - NOTE, I do not have this problem in 1.0, beta 2.

I have a leaflet map with two tile layers (mapbox, and my own) one marker layer, and a GeoJSON layer. What I was finding was that since the GeoJSON layer is dynamically loaded (from a file contents) and that that happens after I had the marker layer, I the marker was getting hidden by z-index.

Ok, easy fix:

```
   theCar = L.marker(mCityCenter, {
         draggable: true,
         rotationOrigin: "32px 32px",
         rotationAngle: 90,
         zIndexOffset: 10000,
         icon: myIcon
     });
     carLayer = theCar;
```

Now, the reason I think I have to do this is that the GeoJSON that I load has lots of marker (GEOJSON points) which I have custom makers for. There can be 4K+ Markers. I think this is filling up the marker pane, and that why zIndexOffset works.

[Don't worry, the map is not that busy, the GeoJSON layer is actually the extension called [Leaflet.Timeline](https://github.com/skeate/Leaflet.timeline), which only shows those markers based on the timline]. But if they they are not physically present in the GeoJSON layer, the timeline will not work]

But that has force me to also self manage the z-index of the pop-up associated with it. Since it was much lower than 10,000.

```
     var popup = L.popup();
     popup.setContent("CAR");
     popup.setLatLng(mCityCenter);
     carLayer.bindPopup(popup);
     popup.addTo(theMap);
     self.CarPopup = popup;
     $(self.CarPopup._container).css('z-index', 20000);
     theMap.closePopup(popup);
```

This is getting really ugly. Obviously, I am doing something wrong here. While it works, I really hate working against the paradigm.

Question: If hypothetically, I had 5 GeoJSON layers in Leaflet, would the vector data all sit in **overlay pane** and the markers sit in the **marker pane**. What happens if I have 4K markers in each pane, how would I keep the "top" level markers from interfering with the lower level ones?

Comment: Which version of Leaflet do you use? With version 0.x, all vector shapes (e.g. coming from your GeoJSON layer) should remain **behind** markers, even if shapes are added later on. Similarly, all pop-ups should remain **above** all shapes and markers. Would you be able to reproduce your issue on plunker or jsfiddle?

Comment: @ghybs I added more detail to the question. But as far as a jsfiddle, that has to wait till after a big demo on Friday, and as I said, I have a work-around though very ugly.

Comment: There should be no difference no matter how many objects you have in your panes. Vector shapes (lines, polygons, circles, etc.) would all be in overlay pane, in the order of insertion. Markers (including points from GeoJSON layers) would all be in markers pane, with their z-index adjusted with `zIndexOffset` and the marker latitude (so that bottom / south most are above upper / north most).

Answer (score 0):

Well, the issue was that there was one marker in the CarLayer (a one Element Feature Group) and several thousand added later in the GeoJSON Timeline. When I scrubbed the timeline, the car would sometimes dis-appear. It all was at very random stretches of the Timeline.  Debugging with Chrome showed it was hidden by zIndex markers that were automatically coming from the GeoJSON Timeline layer. Setting the zIndexOffset for the CarLayer solved the issue. But it seems this is fixed in leaflet 1.0Beta2. So I am marking this solved.